# nx-client issue - no mouse or keyboard input

Tags: ubuntu, nx-client, nx-server

I am using nxserver & nxclient and have run into an issue. Everything connects well and I can see the gnome screen when using nx client. The screen also refreshes as I see new windows pop-up such as the Update Manager.

However, nx client will not accept any input. I try to click on menu items, desktop items but to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so what did you do?

Comment: I have this same problem right now. There is a workaround [here](http://www.nomachine.com/tr/view.php?id=TR05G02223) but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

First look for the session # of your nxclient session:

```
ps aux |grep nxagent
```

You should receive a line like this one:

```
usr/NX/bin/nxagent -D -options /home/sweiss/.nx/C-jer-build.sandvine.com-1002-829246921EF1EA09EB4B745F89CF7B02/options -name NX - sweiss@jer-build.sandvine.com:1002 - il-build4 :1002
```

and reset by writing:

```
DISPLAY=:1002 metacity --replace
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm running NX rootless, so I get: user 12536  0.0  0.0   6508   620 pts/0    S+   19:42   0:00 grep --color=auto nxagent